# On total dominating sets of regular-graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The total dominating set $S$ of a graph $G$ is a set of vertices such that $\forall$ $v \in V(G)$, $v$ has a neighbour in $S$. The dominating set $D$ of a graph $G$ is a set of vertices such that $\forall v \in (V(G) \setminus D)$, $v$ has a neighbour in $D$.

$\gamma_t(G)$ represents the minimum size of a total dominating set of $G$.$\gamma(G)$ represents the minimum size of a dominating set in $G$. Obviously we have $\gamma_t(G)\geq \gamma(G)$ for any graph $G$.

Let $G$ be a triangle-free $k$-regular graph (NOTE: The triangle-freeness is not important in this question) . I make a triangle-free $(k+1)$-regular graph $G'$ as follows:
Take two copies of $G$ and add an edge between the corresponding vertices of the two graphs.

**I want to know whether the following claim is true.**

> $\gamma_t(G') = 2 \times \gamma(G)$

It is obviously true that $\gamma_t(G')\leq 2\times \gamma(G)$: Let $u_1,\ldots ,u_n$. denote vertices of "left" copy of $G$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ denote vertices of "right" copy of $G$ in $G'$. Let $\{u_1,\ldots,u_{|D|} \}$ be a dominating set of $G$.Then $\{ u_1,\ldots,u_{|D|},v_1,\ldots,v_{|D|}\}$ is a total dominating set of $G'$.

Comment: It's not true unfortunately. Take $G=C_7$. $γ(G) =3$ but $γ_t(G') = 5$ Example with triangles would be G being Cartesian product of two $C_3$. [Drawing with marked $γ_t(G')$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da7OH.png)

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples.  But can we construct one for $3$-regular *triangle-free* or higher ?

Comment: Yeah, I should have been more precise with my previous comment I only found some counterexamples not disproved the idea completely, sorry. If you put $G$ triangle-free, $k$-regular with $k\geq 3$ then it's not obvious to me. I tried a bit with no luck though I didn't go past 16 vertices. I'll keep looking :)

Comment: Okay, I think I found it for $k=3$. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5tKT.png) Marked in pink is total dominating set of $G'$, it's $P_3$ and two $P_2$. Yellow vertices are connected to $P_3$ green are connected to $P_2$. And unless I missed something the $γ(G)=4$. I don't have idea for general $k$ though so I'll try working on that.

Comment: Yup! Your example is correct. $k=3$ actually helps a lot (Even though it may be true for higher $k$) .Thanks!

Comment: [I think I also got $ k = 4$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egGgJ.png) with $γ(G)=5$. So I'd lean towards it's not true for higher. And glad I could be of help it has been lots of fun :)